# resizing an action button causes misalignment in the header in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinydashboardplus

I have placed an action button on the header of my shinydashboard that automatically opens the default mail application and fills the To: line. However, when I resize the button, the collapsible sidebar header and the main header get misaligned (please see the picture below for a reference).

Furthermore, I have checked out these posts in SO:

1. [Aligning a text with variable length in the middle of dashboard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434402/aligning-a-text-with-variable-length-in-the-middle-of-dashboard-header)
2. [Align header elements in shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978648/align-header-elements-in-shiny-dashboard)

However, following them did not provide enough help with my issues. Here is the reprex:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(htmltools)
library(DT)


ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
  options = list(sidebarExpandOnHover = TRUE),
  header = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(disable = FALSE,
                                               tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                                                       
                                                       
                                                       tags$a(actionButton(inputId = "email1", label = "",
                                                                           icon = icon("envelope", lib = "font-awesome")
                                                                           ,
                                                                           style='height: 20px; width: 30px;
                                                                        margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px;
                                                                        margin-bottom: 0px; padding:4px 4px 20px 4px;'
                                                       ),
                                                       href="mailto:my_awesome_email_address.com")),
                                               
                                               
                                               
                                               title = tagList(
                                                 tags$span(
                                                   class = "logo-mini", "small"
                                                 ),
                                                 tags$span(
                                                   class = "logo-lg", "LONGER TEXT"
                                                 )
                                               )),
  sidebar = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardSidebar(
    minified= TRUE,
    collapsed = TRUE,
    
    sidebarMenu(
    ),
    tags$script(JS("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';"))
    
  ),
  body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(tabName = "mainPanel_1",
              box(
              )
      )
    ),
    controlbar = NULL,
    footer = NULL
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style for your button:

```r
style='height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transform: translate(5%, -30%);'
```